# Play all songs in music

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmediaitemcollection

I have this code to play all songs in music library (added via iTunes and downloaded in library from Apple Music).
I can not have just the songs. What am I doing wrong?

```
-(IBAction)playAllSongs:(id)sender {

  MPMediaQuery *songsQuery = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];
  NSArray *songsArray = [songsQuery collections];

  MPMediaItemCollection *items =  [MPMediaItemCollection collectionWithItems:songsArray];
  MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer];
  [musicPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection:items]; 
}
```

Comment: is there any problem you facing just clear your ques .. ?

Comment: my code return all media items (pdf, epub, video, songs, etc..) but not only songs.

Comment: show your array, what data you are getting ..

Comment: I have the 4 songs in console (it's right) 'MyApp[338:25524] (
    "<MPConcreteMediaItemCollection: 0x16d7fe20>",
    "<MPConcreteMediaItemCollection: 0x16e7dcb0>",
    "<MPConcreteMediaItemCollection: 0x16e17350>",
    "<MPConcreteMediaItemCollection: 0x16ee7090>"
)' but not in app. Do you have a solution or tips or not?

Comment: when after all this indicate we expect an answer... keyboard phenomena!

Comment: as i said earlier you ques is not clear please edit it and show all the data with array so we can help ..

Comment: Who knows the framework understands that the problem is this line: MPMediaItemCollection * items = [MPMediaItemCollection collectionWithItems: songsArray]; without need of NSLog. Again keyboard phenomena!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my self

```
MPMediaQuery *songsQuery = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];
NSArray *songsArray = [songsQuery items];

MPMediaItemCollection *items =  [MPMediaItemCollection collectionWithItems:songsArray];
MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer];

//[songsQuery addFilterPredicate:[MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyIsCloudItem]]; // for iTunes Match or Apple music to exclude or not songs not in the device

[musicPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection:items];
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answer works but it's a roundabout way to do it.
A simpler way:

```
MPMediaQuery *songs = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];
MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer];
[musicPlayer setQueueWithQuery:songs]
```